# Lablayout and Linairlayout

Tags: android

I am trying to make a app with the tutorial of the developers page, then I would like to display a main.xml in a tabview, instead the textview, which in the tutorial, is in the activity.

How do I tell my tab in activity do display the main.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Set up your tabhost to have an activity in the tab, and then in that activity set its content view to your main.xml:

*tabhost activity*

```
TabHost host = getTabHost(); 
Intent tab1 = new Intent(this, main.class);
host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("one").setIndicator("Tab 1").setContent(tab1));
```

*main.class*

```
setContentView(setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Comment: Thank you! I have tryed it, but maybe this is above my knowledge (dont have much experience with android)
Is there a basis tuotrail (besides the developers page) on tabs, wich includes a main.xml in a tab build in, so I can have an easy start.
Thanks!